# How to put widget in the center and top of two widgets?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-widget

I am designing a widget where, I want to put widget in the center of two rectangular container. My idea is that when I click on it, center widget becomes visible. It looks like this.

[image]

What I wanted to do is that clicking on one grey container or both, this purple widget becomes visible, clicking again, it would disappear. This is my code below.

```
 Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                  width: 70,
                  height: 40,
                color: Colors.indigo,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 70,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: 100,
                      height: 30,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10,),
                    Container(
                      width: 100,
                      height: 30,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

However, with this the widget hides behind two widgets like this.
[image]

Anybody can help me with its positioning?

Comment: Can you put the indigo container to the last? It will work then.

Comment: @AbdullahJaved I putted in the last but it gives pixel over flow error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer.

```
Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 70,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: 100,
                          height: 30,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10,),
                        Container(
                          width: 100,
                          height: 30,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 70,
                    height: 40,
                    color: Colors.indigo,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```